# Wordpress: Large empty (?) white space

Tags: wordpress, containers, space

My website URL: http://piquantblog.com

Thinking it wouldn't come back to haunt me, I gave my container a fixed height as I couldn't figure out the cause of that giant white space you see on the home page below the content and above the footer.  Obviously, this eventually interfered with my layout as I began coding the post pages.

Now I've gone through and made all possible containers height:auto and I can't seem to find the cause of that huge amount of white space. The space is visible in both Chrome and Firefox, so its not a browser issue it seems.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is relative positioning.

I have inspected your code and all of the elements within #container elements are positioned using negative top/left coordinates and relative positioning.

Every time you use relative positioning you should imagine that the space that should have been occupied by the element remains occupied, and the positional coordinates just move the visualisation of the element elsewhere.

If you add up the sum of the heights of those elements they'll be 460+620+6*300 = 2880px in total.

In order to achieve the result you want in a flexible way you should only use **float: left** on the elements, make sure all elements have a well defined **width** (this is important) and preferably a **height** as well (but it's not that important).

And finish the element list with a <br style="clear: both" />

This is a classical rookie mistake. Using relative generates the extra spacing, using fixed/absolute makes the design rigid, using float allows for flexibility and avoids the spaces.

### TL;DR

Remove **position: relative**; **top: NNpx**; **left: NNpx** from all items inside #container, such as #post-16, then use **float:left** on all items in #container.

You'll have to adjust margins/paddings and such to distance the elements after applying the float.

Comment: After removing the position, I see what you're saying.  So is relative positioning in this case not the answer? Would absolute (since it is within a larger container) be more appropriate?

Comment: Absolute means that every post generated by wordpress needs to have its coordinates calculated based on column position, row position. Would you like to do that?

Comment: My issue is also that I'm using children to target these instances of the .hentry class as I'm styling one loop.  So I can't wrap the last 6 instances of the posts in a div or any other html elements for that matter to separate them from the other two.

Comment: All you know is that post-356 is the 13nth post on your page. You have to figgure out on what row and column it should end up in the layout and calculate the coordinates for it. That's pretty counter intuitive if you ask me.

Comment: Can't you do it in the template? Add the necessary extra classes to them in the loop?

Comment: Let me give this a go right now and get back to you. I'm really grateful for the help!

Comment: Also, to clarify, I have one loop where there is one instance of the .hentry class, which is what I need to style.  By using .hentry first-child, nth-child (2) and so on, I can target the instances of the .hentry class so that as I add additional posts, the posts flow through the styling.  In other words, what is currently the first post will transition to the styling of the second post if I add another.  Again, I'll try floating them and see where I get.

Comment: Floating fixed it all, of course! I realized that I had tried this originally, and because I had failed to float the second child, none of the children(?) in question floated properly, and I assumed that floating wouldn't work here.  Really ridiculous mistake thinking about it.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Create a variable $index = 0; outside of the **while** loop, and add a class named ".ordered_".$index that way you can control which object gets which styling without relying on CSS3 selectors (which [don't work everywhere](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child%28%29)); and by everywhere meaning **any bloody internet explorer**

Answer (score 0):

chrome, right click whitespace, inspect this element. you can now life edit as html all the elements and css atributes untill you find the solution.
when you find it edit your css and core files to solve it

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been doing for the last half hour and I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Only half an hour? have you checked the padding and margin values and position values of every relevant object? have you checked the cumulative effects of those?